# How to retrieve a name from the data in response in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js

I have a issue that i want to get the name from the response of api.

Here is what i have, i have response like this:

```
capabilities: (55) ["x:list", "y:create", "z:retrieve"]
created_at: "2021-03-09T14:13:18.214999Z"
test: null
description: "test"
```

What i want to that to have only get the "x:list" from the above

Here is what i am doing is:

```
this.response.data.data
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how you process the data, so I cannot give an exact answer. I guess it would be something like this

```
const { capabilities } = this.response.data
const xList = capabilities.find(item => item === "x:list")
console.log(xList)
```

Comment: if the list ```["x:list", "y:create", "z:retrieve"]``` is long and i want to just get only one value lets say ```p:list```, then how to find it?

Comment: `response.data.find(item => item === "p:list")` will return the element

`response.data.includes("p:list")` checks that the item is in the list